# How to connect iPhone 3GS to a computer monitor without jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, screen-sharing

I have to do a presentation where I want to demo some apps on an iPhone 3GS.

Is there a way to mirror the iPhone screen on a computer screen without jailbreaking?

Answer (score 3):

For a 3GS, no.

There isn't a way on any iOS device aside from the iPad 2 and the iPhone 4S.